# When picking k from a population n, with replacement, how do I determine the optimal n where all of k will be unique?

Tags: sampling

Let say I pick k number of particles from a population n, with replacement, and the population n is derived from picking i number of particles from a pool of 1.0995116e+12 unique particles, with replacement, how do I determine the optimal n for a desired k where all of k is unique?

The experiment is as follows, I start with an initial population of 1.0995116e+12 unique particles. There is a bottle neck where I will sample roughly 35,000 particles from the population into their own unique population, n. This population n will have 35,000 unique particles at near infinite copies, which is why it is with replacement. I want to sample k number of particles from n, where I will have less than 1% of the population being non-unique(I would like them all to be unique, but technical limits may require me to allow some non-unique). Finding a probability distribution to model this has been hard given my lack of statistical knowledge, I am trying to find the optimum number n for a given k, where the population k will have all unique particles.

My approach to this has been to model it computationally and manually pick values of n and k that give me a low non-unique rate. I then run the simulation a large number of times, and plot the distribution of non-unique over unique. I show an example below where n=35000, k=300, and the simulation is run 1,000,000 times. I then plotted a histogram of the proportions of non-unique to k for each simulation.

However, if I want to choose a larger number k I would have to manually run the simulations again and intuitively scale the n to the k after observing the data. I feel that this approach is computationally wasteful, is there a more elegant method?
[image: x-axis are bins of the proportion of non-unique to total chosen particles, y-axis is the percentage of the simulated data that gave the aforementioned proportions where n = 35000 and k = 300]

Comment: I think you might need to restate this problem. If you want to guarantee uniqueness (or 99% uniqueness), just pick one particle. However, I suspect this is not helpful to you. Therefore, try to think of an objective function which would capture what you want. For example, maybe you want to maximize the number of unique particles subject to an expectation that 99% are unique? Then if k is the number of samples, you would maximize k-E(duplicates|k samples) subject to E(duplicates|k samples) < 0.01*k.

Comment: this was extremely helpful, thank you. I am a bit naive in this subject, but I am a little bit familiar with the traveling salesman problem. Would this be in the same vein of thought, in terms of defining the problem and solving using linear programming?

Comment: You might not need to solve it using an optimizer; you could maybe use Lagrange multipliers. If you do use an optimizer, the problem might be an LP. Either way, thinking about the objective function is a good way to arrive at a well-stated problem.